# Compiler Error when Creating a Macro/Environment

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to create a new command or environment or something to format what is essentially a section, but it needs to have it's own counter. I would like to not use any of the \section \subsection etc. as I go into the full depth that they provide.

The idea being I would type in something similar to...

```
\session{Hello World}
```

... and it would output something like (although centred) ...

> ***Session 1 : Hello World***

The command I've currently got is as follows:

```
\newcounter{sessioncounter}
\newcommand{\session}
{
\begin{center}
\begin{emph}
\begin{textbf}
\begin{Large}
Session \value{sessioncounter}\stepcounter{sessioncounter}: 
}{
\end{Large}
\end{textbf}
\end{emph}
\end{center}
}
```

Trying this exactly, the Latex compiler throws the following error (note, this is before \begin{document} has even been called).

> LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Large}

I've also tried creating a new environment by literally swapping out \newcommand{\session} to \newenvironment{session}. While this compiles, I get the following error on the line of \begin{session}.

> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> ```
>         <to be read again>
> ```
>
> \aftergroup
>
> l.13 \begin{session}

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I presume by the error that newcommand can't be used exactly with this syntax for what I want; however, I'm also confused as to why the environment does not work either.

Comment: `\newcommand` would define a command `\session` you are defining an environment so `\newenvironment{session}` (and unrelated but you want `%` at the end of all the lines in the definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition matches the format of an *environment*, not a command.

This is how environments are defined:

```
\newenvironment{example}{<starting commands>}{<ending commands>}
```

They are then used like this:

```
\begin{example}
<text>
\end{example}
```

But I think you want a *command* that takes one argument, as in this example. Also, `\thesessioncounter` gives you the number as text; `\value` is for use in other internal commands. (I've adjusted the formatting commands a bit as well.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{sessioncounter}
\newcommand{\session}[1]{%
    \hfil\bgroup\Large\itshape\bfseries 
    Session~\thesessioncounter: #1\egroup\par\bigskip
    \stepcounter{sessioncounter}%
}

\begin{document}
\session{Hello World}
\session{Hello again}
\session{Hello for the last time}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, got few questions from your formatting though if you don't mind. What do the %s do? I gather the \bgroup and \egroup is an alternative to a 'scope' (excuse my C++ terminology). What's the ~ used for?

Comment: `%` tells TeX to ignore the subsequent EOL; `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are the same as `{` and `}` and yes, limit the scope of the commands in between; `~` indicates a non-breaking space, typically used before the numeral in cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do `\begin{textbf}` or `\begin{emph}` and you shouldn't do `\begin{Large}` either.

You want

```
\newcommand{\session}[1]{%
  \begin{center}\Large\itshape\bfseries
    \stepcounter{sessioncounter}%
    Session \value{sessioncounter}: #1%
  \end{center}%
}
```

in the preamble and use

```
\session{Hello world}
```

in the document.